# Implication of applying browser caching policy in .Net Core 3.1 application

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, asp.net-core-3.1

The application is getting cached only in IE browser (not in chrome and chromium). I am not sure why.
But I found a work around by disabling cache in the middleware.

```
services.AddMvc(options => {
    options.Filters.Add(new ResponseCacheAttribute() { NoStore = true, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None });
})
```

Are there any bad implications of implementing above solution in the project?

Comment: It is a server-side code to prevent caching. I did not see any bad implication from the above line of code. Further, it depends upon your code and application. You can check whether it is giving any unexpected result or not.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, I think the bad implication of implementing the above code is that it is hitting the database every time to get the record as the above code does not store records in the cache. So it will be a performance issue. Please let me know your thought.

Comment: I suggest trying to add these 2 lines in the `<head>` part and see whether it helps to fix the issue for the IE browser. ` <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">` you can comment your above-mentioned workaround while testing this suggestion. If this suggestion works then you not need to use the workaroud. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/browsers/how-to-prevent-caching)